# Changing TOC to include figure and table and fancy header

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

How can I change the TOC to display Figure: X and Table X? Also if you notice in the header there is a somewhat fancy header with the name and a horizontal line, I would like to get that too.

I currently have like this like.
[image]

And I want to make it look like this.
[image]
[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: So I manged to get Table and Figure in there. Using \renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure\ }
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table\ }
\newlength{\mylenf}
\settowidth{\mylenf}{\cftfigpresnum}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\dimexpr\mylenf+2.5em}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\dimexpr\mylenf+2.5em} missing only the header now :)

Comment: Can anyone help?